# Quaternion group associativity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions

Consider the eight objects $\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k$ with multiplication rules:

$ij=k,jk=i,ki=j,ji=-k,kj=-i,ik=-j,i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$,

where the minus signs behave as expected and $1$ and $-1$ multiply as expected. Show that these objects form a group containing exactly one involution.

Well, it is easy to determine closure from the definition. $1$ is clearly the identity, and the inverses can also be determined $(i,-i),(j,-j),(k,-k)$, $-1$ with itself, and $1$ with itself. The only involution is $-1$. Is there an easy way to check associativity of this group? There are too many possible combinations $(ab)c=a(bc)$ to check directly. ($8^3$ possible combinations)

Comment: First idea: negatives work as expected, so only need to check associativity of {i,j,k} which is 3^3 or 3^2 after symmetry.

Comment: second idea: find matrices that multiply as requested, then you know the multiplication is associative.

Comment: @Jack : If this was an answer I'd upvote it. You should just copy paste it down there.

Comment: You probably intended a minus sign in $i^2=\dots=-1$.

Comment: My answer assumes $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$, since otherwise $\pm i,\pm j, \pm k$ are all also involutions.

Comment: There's probably a typo in $i^2=..=1$ should be a $-1$ for the actual quaternions multiplication rule

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One idea that saves some work, but still might make your eyes cross is to realize that negatives work as expected, so you don't need to test associativity with 1, -1, or any of the negative i,j,k. That leaves only $\{i,j,k\}^3$ which is 27 tests, each requiring 4 very easy multiplications, 108 easy lookups. If you notice that $i \mapsto j \mapsto k$ is an automorphism, then you can say that $a=i$ in $a(bc) \stackrel{?}{=} (ab)c$ reducing it to 9 checks, 36 easy multiplications.

However, a method with more fringe benefits is to find matrices that multiply as expected. It is easiest if you know complex numbers, since $i$ and $j$ are both like $\sqrt{-1}$, but they don't commute.

Hopefully you can discover the matrices by yourself, but maybe it is tricky without a lot of experience. Here are matrices that work ($\sqrt{-1}$ is any fixed square root of $-1$ in a field of characteristic not 2, say $\mathbb{C}$ for instance; take 1 to be the identity matrix, and if $a$ corresponds to the matrix $A$, then $-a$ corresponds to $-A$, so that negatives work just like expected).

> $$i = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & -\sqrt{-1} \end{bmatrix}, \qquad j = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad k = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \sqrt{-1} \\ \sqrt{-1} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: The matrix method involves 16 nonzero products, so is faster, unless of course you don't guess the correct matrices on your first try. :P

Comment: And how does the 9 checks method work? I can't really see it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is detailed in the first paragragraph of this answer. Which step precisely don't you understand?

Comment: The fact that you can take $a=i$ without loss of generality

Comment: This is because there is an automorphism permuting $i,j,k$ which sends $i$ to $j,$ and another one which sends $i$ to $k.$ @CharlesJA Using them, proving $a(bc)=(ab)c$ for $\{a,b,c\}=\{i,j,k\}$ reduces to proving it for $a=i$ and $\{b,c\}=\{j,k\}.$

Comment: Ok, and in this way I would have 2 cases taking $b=j, c=k$ and $b=k, c=j$, but what about the other 7 cases? They are the ones that involve $1$ and $-1$? Thanks @AnneBauval

Comment: Sorry @CharlesJA the second part of my previous comment was erroneous. Please replace it by: "Using them, proving $a(bc)=(ab)c$ for $\{a,b,c\}\subset\{i,j,k\}$ reduces to proving it for $a=i$ and  $(b,c)\in\{i,j,k\}^2$". You are thus left with $9$ cases.

Comment: @CharlesJA These "extra cases" were discarded in the first sentence of the answer. What Jack implicitely meant was: if $a,$ $b,$ or $c$ is equal to $1$, $a(bc)=(ab)c$ is obvious. And if $a',b',c'$ are respectively equal to $\epsilon_aa,\epsilon_bb,\epsilon_cc$ with $\epsilon_x=1$ or $-1$, then $a(bc)=(ab)c\implies a'(b'c')=(a'b')c'.$ This allowed him to consider $\{a,b,c\}\subset\{i,j,k\}$ instead of $\subset\{\pm1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}.$

Comment: Ok, understood. And to prove the fact that there exist those automorphisms, would it be necessary to construct them? Aprreciate your effort to solve my doubts @AnneBauval. Oh, yes, I deleted the previous comment because then I read the first sentence of the answer but you made it much more clear.

Comment: He did: "notice that $i \mapsto j \mapsto k$ is an automorphism" (hence so is its iterate, $i \mapsto k\mapsto j$) @CharlesJA

Comment: Alright, you made it quite easy to understand everything. Just one final detail, the process to compute $i\cdot(-i)$ using the properties defined in the group and the associative would be: $i\cdot(-i)=i\cdot[(-1)\cdot i]=i \cdot [i \cdot (- 1)]=[i\cdot i] \cdot (-1)=(-1)\cdot(-1)=1$ ,right?

Comment: I would rather say that $a\cdot b$ have been specified for *every* $a,b\in G=\{\pm1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$ when defining the operation on $G,$ but not explicitely (too boring): "$i^2=-1$ and $-1$ multiplies as expected" includes the *definition* $i\cdot(-i)=-i^2=(-1)^2=1$. @CharlesJA

Answer (score 0):

This very old question keeps getting linked to by other closed questions, and I thought it therefore deserved another answer.

Another option for proving associativity of $Q_8$ is to generalize. The elements of $Q_8$ may be regarded as a collection of "units" for a much larger quaternion algebra $Q$, consisting of all expressions of the form $a + bi + cj + dk$ where $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers, not all equal to zero. The product operation on such expressions is defined in the obvious manner: distribute, simplify, and collect terms, **taking care to use the anticommutativity formulas $ij=-ji=k$ when needed**, to get
\begin{align*}
(a + bi + cj + dk) (a' + b'i + c'j + d'k) &= (aa' - bb' - cc' - dd') \\ 
&\quad+ (ab' + ba' + cd' - dc') i \\
&\quad+ (ac' + ca' + db' - bd') j \\
&\quad+ (ad' + da' + bc' - cb') k
\end{align*}
And now "all" you have to do is prove that product operation is associative!

So, you do not escape tedium in this manner.

*But*, you end up proving something more general and, hence, more valuable, namely associativity of multiplication in $Q$.