# Associative property of the quaternion group

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove that the well-known quaternion group is a group and I am stuck with the association. Because, proving directly that $a*(b*c) =(a*b) *c$ for all its elements requires a lot of cases. However, I looked for this question and found the following thread:
[Quaternion group associativity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401506/quaternion-group-associativity)
in which is mentioned a way of reducing the problem to only 9 cases. However, I can't see how to do it. Appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: This is detailed in the first paragraph of [the accepted answer in the post you linked to](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/401518/386889). Which step precisely don't you understand? + may be we should answer there, not here.

Comment: I closed this question because it should be clarified by making comments on the duplicate.